# Rotate Empty on Local X-Axis using Python Script

Tags: python, scripting, transforms

I have created a grid of hexagons.  I want to animate the rotation of a series of them diagonally, so I have parented each hexagon to its own Empty, and rotated the Empty's orientation to the angle I want to rotate the hexagons at.  But when I try to rotate each Empty on its local x-axis using python script, I can't seem to get the expected rotation.  What I've tried so far:

Selected Empty in 3D viewport, then ran (where the value "1.5708" is the equivalent of rotating 90 degrees):

```
bpy.context.object.rotation.euler[0] = 1.5708
```

or . . .

```
bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=1.5708, 
                         axis=(0.866025, 0.5, 0), 
                         constraint_axis=(True, False, False), 
                         constraint_orientation='LOCAL', 
                         mirror=False,
                         proportional='DISABLED', 
                         proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', 
                         proportional_size=1, 
                         release_confirm=True)
```

The first one results in an error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "", line 1, in 
>       AttributeError: 'Object' object has no attribute 'rotation'

The second one rotates the Empty, but not according to local x-axis. (looks like maybe global x-axis)

Note: the above commands come from the info panel where first one is the same as setting rotation in the "Properties" panel (<kbd>N</kbd> key in 3D Viewport) and second one is the result of using the 3D Manipulation Widget

I am using Blender 2.73a on Mac OSX 10.8.5

Comment: The first one needs to be rotation_euler (underscore instead of . )

Answer (score 4):

Your first attempt did not work because (as Ray Mairlot pointed out) the attribute is `rotation_euler`, not `rotation.euler`. Further more, with the proper notation it will only rotate the active object, not all objects selected.

This five line script rotates all selected objects by 90° on the local X axis.

```
import bpy
from math import pi
for ob in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    ob.rotation_euler[0] = pi/2
    ob.convert_space(from_space='LOCAL', to_space='WORLD')
```

The `from math import pi` line is just so we can use `pi/2` instead of `1.5708` as the value to rotate by.